Using Romans 9:16 can you explain the fundamental differences between Mercy and Grace
Romans 9:16 (NIV) says:

It does not, therefore, depend on human desire or effort, but on God’s mercy.

According to my understanding, if its not of works or effort i.e. does not depend on one's effort then its by Grace. But the text above says Mercy. i have checked in multiple versions (KJV, AMP, TLB,GNT,  etc) and they are also saying Mercy instead of grace. Unfortunately I don't know Greek...
In summary, I understand Mercy versus Grace as: Mercy is God not giving us what we do deserve; Grace is God giving us something we do not deserve (Unmerited favor).
So should Romans 9:16 read as: "It does not, therefore, depend on human desire or effort, but on God’s grace."
If Not, thats what is making ask for the fundamental differences between Mercy and Grace

First, one cannot tell the difference in meaning between grace and mercy according to Rom 9:16 because only the word "mercy" appears in the verse.  If one wishes to have a verse where both appear, then one should consult other places such as 2 John 3, 1 Tim 1:2, Heb 4:16, 10:29, etc.
The distinction in meaning between these two words in the NT is given by any reputable lexicon.  Here I will quote BDAG:

χάρις (charis = grace). According to BDAG this word has five different shades of meaning:


a winning quality or attractiveness that invites favorable reaction, graciousness, attractiveness, charm, winsomeness, eg, Luke 4:22, Col 4:6
a beneficent disposition toward someone, favor, grace, gracious care/help, goodwill, eg, luke 2:40, Acts 11:2, 14:26, 15;40, Rom 3:24, 5:15, etc
practical application of goodwill, (a sign of) favor, gracious deed/gift, benefaction, eg, Acts 24:27, 25:3, 9, 2 Cor 1:15, 8:4, 6, 19, 1 Cor 16:3, 2, etc
exceptional effect produced by generosity, favor, eg, 2 Cor 8:1, 9:14, 8, Rom 1:5, 12:3, 15:15, 1 Cor 3:10, etc
response to generosity or beneficence, thanks, gratitude, eg, Luke 17:9, 2 Tim 1:3, 1 Tim 1:12, Phlm 7, Heb 12:28, etc.


ἔλεος (eleos = mercy). BDAG gives this single meaning:


kindness or concern expressed for someone in need, mercy, compassion,
pity, clemency, eg, Matt 9:13, 12:7, James, 2:13, Luke 1:50, Gal 6:16,
1 Tim 1:2, 2 Tim 1:2, 2 John 3, Jude 2, etc.

It is immediately apparent that the meanings of these two words slightly overlap.  However, in modern theological jargon (in contradistinction to Biblical usage) "mercy" and "grace" have acquired technical meanings much narrower than NT usage.  Therefore, I will resist the temptation to expound these technical meanings and leave the NT usage and vocabulary to speak for itself.
The above is particularly true in Romans 9 where some theologians insist that it teaches limited atonement.  For a few comments on this, see the appendix below.
APPENDIX - Romans 9
Some insist that Rom 9 teaches limited atonement (or predestination).  For example, some will specifically quote v13: “Jacob I loved and Esau I hated”; and v14, “I will have mercy on whom I have mercy, and I will have compassion on whom I have compassion”.  V19-23 appears to be the “magna carter” of limited atonement.  So, is Rom 9 really discussing limited atonement, despite all the many Bible references listed earlier?  How should we understand this passage?
We should observe the following facts:

Background:  Passages like Jer 7:4 clearly show that the Jews regarded their position as the chosen people of God as the source of their spiritual pride.  That is, because of all that God had bestowed on them, they believed they must be saved and were guaranteed God’s favor and eternal life.  Thus, the doctrine of free grace came as a very big shock.  Paul is at pains to point out that not all who are (physical or genetic) Israelites are (spiritual) Israelites.  Gentiles could become spiritual Israelites by “the promise”.  God was now selecting gentiles to be His representatives without excluding the Jews.  Even in ancient literal Israel, membership of Israel was entirely voluntary not genetic.
The chosen nation status of Israel was about their vocation as evangelists to teach the world, not their status as saved.  This is confirmed by the analogy of the potter in v21.
Romans 9 is NOT discussing individuals.  God chose the nation that came from Jacob to do the job of providing the spiritual enlightenment to the world and being the progenitors of Christ.  See v 3-5.
If Paul is teaching limited atonement in Rom 9 then he is very confused because v6 and v7 teaches the opposite.  “… not all who are descended from Israel are Israel.  Nor because they are his descendants are they all Abraham’s children.”  That is, being “chosen” (or “elect”) descendant of Abraham does not make a person a member of spiritual Israel; rather it was whether that person becomes a person of the promise, that choses to accept God’s grace.
Paul’s summary and conclusion to his long (and admittedly difficult) argument in Rom 9:30-32 is equally clear – being a physical member of literal Israel does not make a person a real spiritual Israelite.  The real question is whether a person becomes a person “of the promise”, that is, decides to accept Jesus.  (See also v24 where Paul again confirms that the chosen are called from both Jews and Gentiles.)
Loved vs hated (v13):  This is a piece of classic Hebrew idiom that employs rhetorical hyperbole.  It is obvious that God loves all people and hates no one because “God is love” (1 John 4:8, 16).  A simple comparison with Mal 1:2, 3 (that v13 quotes), Luke 14:26, 27 and Gen 29:31-33 (where the word “hated” is used) shows this Hebrew idiom well.


wow. thank you sir...

Romans 1-8 are all about teaching the believing Jews who still want to continue in the works of the law, ceremonies, circumcision, rituals, sacrifices of the priesthood, temple worship, that the covenant that God with Israel under Moses was dead and the New Covenant in Jeremiah 31:31 was initiated at the crucifixion of Christ.
The ninth chapter is about how God chooses how he will accomplish his plan and as individuals we have no say in it.
So Romans 9:16, when it says not to him that wills not to him that wills but God that showed mercy.
Grace comes from mercy
In other words, when God says he's going to have mercy, mercy is a mechanism that triggers a favor, which is what Grace is Grace means to favor someone.
In this case, God had mercy on those individuals he chose to bring forth his plan, and as a result of that, they were favored (Graced), to be part of his plan.
In this sense, Grace is still in play.
By the way, the only time Grace is unmerited in favor is when God offered Salvation to us. The offer is unconditional and offered to all and upon all.
But eternal life is something you earn after you accept the unconditional offer.

Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I also recommend going through the Help Center's sections on both asking and answering questions.

Is there a passage that supports the idea that "eternal life is something you earn after you accept the unconditional offer."?
